# Find the modulus of continuity of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, at $I=(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Find the modulus of continuity of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, at $I=(0, 1)$.

My try:

Let $|x-y|<r$. Let $x=0^+$ and $y=0+r$

Then $|f(0^+)-f(0+r)| = |\infty -\frac{1}{r}|=\infty$

I'm not sure if my method is correct. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not correct for following reasons:

- In the definition of (global) modulus of continuity, only elements of the definition set are used. $0^+$ is not such an element.
- As a consequence, if you use limits like $f(0^+)$ to compute the modulus of continuity, you should prove how  a limit can be used.

What you can do is to compute

$$\frac{f(1/n)-f(1/2n)}{1/n -1/2n}=2n^2$$ and deduce that the modulus of continuity is equal to $\infty$.